# Java SOA Client (Rejected By Policy)

Tags: java, webservice, soap

Escribo con la esperanza de que puedan ayudarme, tengo un cliente SOA, que utiliza WSSE y Firma digital, cuando consume el servicio, devuelve un error que indica "Rejected By Policy", de acuerdo con la documentación, tiene que ver con  nombre de usuario y contraseña del WSSE, pero lo he validado y es correcto, ¿alguien tendrá una idea de qué más puedo revisar?

El cliente está escrito en Java con las clases de SOAPMessage, SOAPEnvelope, etc y el servicio utiliza adicionalmente HTTPS, en los encabezados utiliza BinaryToken, UsernameToken, Timestamp y Signature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente he encontrado una solución, lo comento por si a alguien más le ayuda, realmente el problema era que yo armaba correctamente mi SOAP Message, pero al especificar el Namespaces de los prefijos WSSE y WSU, estaba indicando:

wsse="http:....**oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0**" lo cual es incorrecto, por lo tanto, el servidor donde se encuentra alojado el servicio a consumir, no identificaba mis parámetros de Usuario y Password y generaba el Rejected By Policy, se debe vigilar que se especifique correctamente el Namespaces de todos los prefijos del mensaje.

El namespace correcto es : wsse="http:....**oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0**".